# MYSQL SELECT max(ID) WHERE Onderdeel_ID=$Onderdeel_ID

Tags: mysql, select

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT max(Cardex_ID) FROM cardex WHERE Onderdeel_ID=$Onderdeel_ID");
>           if (!$result) {
>               die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
>           }

```
    $Cardex_ID = mysql_result($result, 0, 'Cardex_ID');

    echo $Cardex_ID;

    mysql_query("UPDATE cardex SET PADate=$PAdate, PAhours=$PAhours, PAcycles=$PAcycles, PAlanding=$PAlanding WHERE Cardex_ID=$Cardex_ID");
```

Comment: I would recomend you to start using PDO for connection go the DB. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php. Did you try a var_dump in $result and see what you get?

Comment: `mysql_error()` will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I have a connection, that isnt the problem. But i want the max cardex_id but i dont have a result. it stops at if(!$result)

Comment: are you sure that Onderdeel_ID is a string? usualy Id's are of type number. maybe remove the quotes and test again. Furthermore are you sure that $Onderdeel_ID is given. Add one echo more to test the value of that variable.

Comment: @stefan what is the mysql_error() showing??

Comment: The variable is Onderdeel_ID is there... but i wil try to remove the quotes

Comment: Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Cardex_ID not found in MySQL result index 10 in C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\School\UsbWebserver\root\VOT officieel\Cardex.php on line 193

Comment: is the spelling / alphabet case, of "Cardex_ID" matching the one with the db ?

Comment: Lol Allready found it.. you need an As after your MAX(ID)

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you to use a [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to connect to your databse instead of using that generic connection. 
Also if the $Onderdeel_ID is a number you shouldn't need the `""`

```
   $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME','DB_USER','DB_PASS');
    $sql = 'SELECT max(Cardex_ID) FROM cardex WHERE Onderdeel_ID='. $Onderdeel_ID;
    $result = $db->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo 'SELECT';
    if (!$result) {
      echo 'RESULT';
    }
```

NOTE: also valid and preferred is using the statement `prepare` to prevent SQL injections:

```
    $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB_NAME','DB_USER','DB_PASS');
    $db->prepare ( 'SELECT max(Cardex_ID) FROM cardex WHERE Onderdeel_ID=:Onderdeel_ID');
    $result = $db->execute( array( ':Onderdeel_ID' => $Onderdeel_ID ) );
```

Also if you keep having problems check that your `$Onderdeel_ID` is being passed. a simple `var_dump($Onderdeel_ID);` would do the trick

Comment: -1. Equally bad in terms of escaping vital parts of the query.

Comment: You should use prepared statements, e.g. `$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT .... WHERE onderdeel_id=:onderdeel'); ... $stmt->execute(array(':onderdeel' => $onderdeel_id));`

Comment: Thats best practice not a must and given that he is not even using PDO i felt that introducing to many new concepts would confuse the author of the post rather than help him.

Comment: This is meant as constructive criticism; improving answers should be preferred over defending them.

Comment: I understand your point. I amended my answer accordingly. But not long ago I was learning PDO and the prepare with the `?` or the `:` variables statements would confused me. I think that when you are just starting sometimes too many new concepts can be overwhelming for someone who never touched PDO. Sometimes less is more.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to improve the answer :)